# How to modify Home Page of every Wiki site created, using Client Side Methods

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

What I am trying to do is:  adding a web part to Enterprise Wiki Home Page so each newly created Wiki Home Page will have that web part automatically.

I am working on SP 2013 and already familiar with server-side solution development and I know I can create a feature/event receiver to change home page of a wiki site that's created.

But what is the best/recommended way to achieve this using Client Side methods? Or is there one? I want to move away from traditional farm solution-based methods to CSOM / JSOM / Add-ins etc. But with this requirement, I do not have much time to research. 
I need a jump start, so any recommendations will be highly appreciated and very welcome!